# Is it possible to run Azure DevOps pipeline tasks in for loop using Classic UI?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have pipeline that was configured using UI (not directly using yaml file). I have many different configuration variants and for each of these I have to run the same seperate Task in this pipeline. I found that it is possible using yaml file but could not find any information about UI approach. Thought that I might be able to run powershell task and run other tasks from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of this time, however, running tasks in for loop using Classic UI pipeline is not supported. You need to add the tasks multiple times to let them run multiples times.

The good news is that you can use task groups to simplify this process.

> A task group allows you to encapsulate a sequence of tasks, already defined in a pipeline, into a single reusable task that can be added to a pipeline, just like any other task. You can choose to extract the parameters from the encapsulated tasks as configuration variables, and abstract the rest of the task information.

Click [Task groups for builds and releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=azure-devops#before-you-create-a-task-group) for detailed steps.